# Form Validation on Twitter Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, validation, email, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a working form validation that checks fields before sending the email trough the contact form.

The form validation won't work inside the twitter bootstrap Modal.
The script checks in JS if all the fields are filled and are correct.
Then sends the information to the php file for processing and returns false or true in AJAX back to the JS file that confirms to the user if the email is send or not.

When i tried to plug this in to the Bootstrap Modal the AJAX true wont return to the JS file and it just displays "true" in the browser window.

It needs to send the "true" to the JS file so the "send button" changes in "messages succesfully send" when clicking send it redirects to email.php.

So how can the "true" value be passed on to the JS file and keep the modal open to change the send button into the successfull message?

The code is as following:

**HTML**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                <img class="small-logo" src="http://www.website.nl/img/logo.jpg">

              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                        <form class="popup-form" data-async data-target="#myModal" id="contact_form" action="email.php" method="POST">
                        <div class="forminput">
                            <p>Aanhef</p>

                                <input type="radio" name="aanhef" value="dhr" id="aanhef" required="required" />
                                <label for="dhr">Dhr.</label>
                                <input type="radio" name="aanhef" value="mvr" id="aanhef" required="required"/>
                                <label for="mvr">Mvr.</label>

                            <div id="aanhef_error" class="error">Kies uw aanhef</div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="forminput">
                            <p>Achternaam</p>
                          <input type='text' name='naam' id='naam' required="required">
                          <div id='naam_error' class='error'>Vul een geldige naam in</div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="forminput">
                        <p>Voornaam</p>                     
                          <input type='text' name='voornaam' id='voornaam' required="required">
                          <div id='voornaam_error' class='error'>Vul een geldige voornaam in</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="forminput">
                        <p>Telefoonnummer</p>
                            <input type='text' name='telefoon' id='telefoon' required="required">
                            <div id='telefoon_error' class='error'>Vul een geldig telefoon nummer in</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="forminput">
                        <p>Straatnaam</p>
                            <input type='text' name='straatnaam' id='straatnaam' required="required">
                            <div id='straatnaam_error' class='error'>Vul een geldige straatnaam in</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="forminput">
                        <p>Huisnummer</p>
                            <input type='text' name='huisnummer' id='huisnummer' required="required">
                            <div id='huisnummer_error' class='error'>Vul een geldig huisnummer in</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="forminput">
                        <p>Postcode</p>
                            <input type='text' name='postcode' id='postcode' required="required">
                            <div id='postcode_error' class='error'>Vul een geldige postcode in</div>
                        </div>


                        <div id='mail_success' class='success'>Message successfully send!</div>
                        <div id='mail_fail' class='error'>Sending email failed try emailing to email@email.com</div>

                        <div class="clear"></div>

                        <div id='submit'>
                          <input type='submit' id='send_message' value='Verstuur'>
                        </div>

                        </form>


                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#send_message').click(function(e){

        //Stop form submission & check the validation
        e.preventDefault();

        // Variable declaration
        var error = false;
        var aanhef = $('input[name=aanhef]:checked').val(); 
        var naam = $('#naam').val();
        var voornaam = $('#voornaam').val();
        var straatnaam = $('#straatnaam').val();
        var huisnummer = $('#huisnummer').val();
        var postcode = $('#postcode').val();
        var telefoon = $('#telefoon').val();

        // Form field validation
        if (aanhef == undefined) {
            var error = true;
            $('#aanhef_error').fadeIn(500);
        }
        else {
            $('#aanhef_error').fadeOut(500);
        }

        if(naam.length < 3){
            var error = true;
            $('#naam_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#naam_error').fadeOut(500);
        }

        if(voornaam.length < 3){
            var error = true;
            $('#voornaam_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#voornaam_error').fadeOut(500);
        }

        if(straatnaam.length < 6){
            var error = true;
            $('#straatnaam_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#straatnaam_error').fadeOut(500);
        }

        if(huisnummer == ""){
            var error = true;
            $('#huisnummer_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#huisnummer_error').fadeOut(500);
        }

        if(postcode.length < 5){
            var error = true;
            $('#postcode_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#postcode_error').fadeOut(500);
        }

        if(telefoon.length < 8){
            var error = true;
            $('#telefoon_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#telefoon_error').fadeOut(500);
        }


        // If there is no validation error, next to process the mail function
        if(error == false){
           // Disable submit button just after the form processed 1st time successfully.
            $('#send_message').attr({'disabled' : 'true', 'value' : 'Versturen...' });

            /* Post Ajax function of jQuery to get all the data from the submission of the form as soon as the form sends the values to email.php*/
            $.post("email.php", $("#contact_form").serialize(),function(result){
                //Check the result set from email.php file.
                if(result == 'sent'){
                    //If the email is sent successfully, remove the submit button
                     $('#submit').remove();
                    //Display the success message
                    $('#mail_success').fadeIn(500);
                }else{
                    //Display the error message
                    $('#mail_fail').fadeIn(500);
                    // Enable the submit button again
                    $('#send_message').removeAttr('disabled').attr('value', 'Send The Message');
                }
            });
        }
    });    
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$to  = 'email@email.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'email2@email.com';

$subject = ' Subject of email'; 

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $_REQUEST['naam'] . "<br>";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $_REQUEST['email'] . "<br>";




$message .= 'Aanhef: ' . $_REQUEST['aanhef'] . "<br>";
$message .= 'Achternaam: ' . $_REQUEST['naam'] . "<br>";
$message .= 'Voornaam: ' . $_REQUEST['voornaam'] . "<br>";
$message .= 'Straatnaam: ' . $_REQUEST['straatnaam'] . "<br>";
$message .= 'Huisnummer: ' . $_REQUEST['huisnummer'] . "<br>";
$message .= 'Postcode: ' . $_REQUEST['postcode'] . "<br>";
$message .= 'Telefoon: ' . $_REQUEST['telefoon'] . "<br>";


if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    // Transfer the value 'sent' to ajax function for showing success message.
    echo 'sent';
}
else
{
    // Transfer the value 'failed' to ajax function for showing error message.
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

Comment: Your problem may be that you are not returning JSON.  Before you echo back your response in the php, do 2 things: 1. `header('Content-type: application/json');` and 2. try returning JSON rather than just a plain string.

Comment: The strange thing is that this piece of code works. But when i put the contactform in a twitter bootstrap modal the parsing from the PHP back to the JS doesn't work. Trying to get my head around the reason why this wont work

Comment: yeah i re-read your question and realized that.  i'm still a bit unclear on what this means: "When i tried to plug this in to the Bootstrap Modal the AJAX true wont return to the JS file and it just displays "true" in the browser window." where is true displayed in the windos?  what do you mean by the AJAX true won't "return to the JS file" -- I don't see the AJAX returning "true" anywhere.